# show and hide control using javascript based on another dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to hide a control using JavaScript based on the selection of an item in a dropdown list.

Here's what I currently have:

```
function DDLDGChanged() {
    var text = $("#<%= DDLDG.ClientID %> option:selected").text();
    alert(text);
    if (text == "DG") {
        document.getElementById('#<%=DDLPsaGroup.ClientID%>').style.display  = "block";
        document.getElementById('#<%=Label29.ClientID%>').style.display  = "block";
        document.getElementById('<%=txtClass.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('#<%=DDLPsaGroup.ClientID%>').style.display  = "none";
        document.getElementById('#<%=Label29.ClientID%>').style.display  = "none";
        document.getElementById('<%=txtClass.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what issue you are facing?

Comment: i want to hide dropdown but above code not work

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can use `jQuery`, why you are relying on `Javascript` code. But going by your code, you are mixing both do it either like this:-

1. Your Way:-

   ```
   function DDLDGChanged() {
       var text = $("#<%= DDLDG.ClientID %> option:selected").text();
       alert(text);
       if (text == "DG") {
        document.getElementById('<%=DDLPsaGroup.ClientID%>').style.display  = "block";
        document.getElementById('<%=Label29.ClientID%>').style.display  = "block";
        document.getElementById('<%=txtClass.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('<%=DDLPsaGroup.ClientID%>').style.display  = "none";
        document.getElementById('<%=Label29.ClientID%>').style.display  = "none";
        document.getElementById('<%=txtClass.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
       }
   }
   ```

Please note, when you use `Javascript` method, no need to use `#` to fetch the control.

2. Do it with pure jQuery itself, like the way you have retrieved `text` variable.